# Exporting to Excel based on filter with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, maatwebsite-excel

I am working on a view that allows users to select a staff member then a date range and when they click the filter button, it will only show that staff member's records for that date period. I have that working but I want to implement an export to excel feature for that staff member and range but when I click export, all my records get exported to excel. Does anyone know what is the right direction to go in?

Controller:

```
 public function exportvehicles()
    {
        return Excel::download(new ExportV, 'users.xlsx');
    }
```

Model:

```
class ExportV implements FromCollection
{
    public function collection()
    {
        $startDate = request()->input('startDate', '2021-01-01');
        $endDate = request()->input('endDate', '2021-12-12');
        return VehicleLog::join('vehicle', 'vehicleslog.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicle.id')
            ->join('smsstaff', 'vehicleslog.smsstaff_key', '=', 'smsstaff.smsstaff_key')
            ->when(request()->input('smsstaff_key'), function ($query) {
                $query->where('smsstaff.smsstaff_key', request()->input('smsstaff_key'));
            })
            ->whereDate('log_dt', '>=', $startDate)
            ->whereDate('log_dt', '<=', $endDate)
            ->get();
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can done query on controller before sending it to an ExportV, this will make you easy to implement multiple type of filter.

Controller :

```
public function exportvehicles()
{
   $startDate = request()->input('startDate', '2021-01-01');
   $endDate = request()->input('endDate', '2021-12-12');
   $item = VehicleLog::join('vehicle', 'vehicleslog.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicle.id')
            ->join('smsstaff', 'vehicleslog.smsstaff_key', '=', 'smsstaff.smsstaff_key')
            ->when(request()->input('smsstaff_key'), function ($query) {
                $query->where('smsstaff.smsstaff_key', request()->input('smsstaff_key'));
            })
            ->whereDate('log_dt', '>=', $startDate)
            ->whereDate('log_dt', '<=', $endDate)
            ->get();
   return Excel::download(new ExportV($item), 'users.xlsx');
}
```

ExcelV :

```
class ExcelV implements FromCollection
{
  protected $item;
  function __constuct ($item) {
    $this->item = $item;
  }
  public function collection() {
    return $this->item;
  }
}
```

Comment: I get a `Call to a member function all() on null` error. Any idea why?

Comment: where is `all()` is from. If it's from excelV, I suggest you use `FromArray` instead of `FromCollection` .